# Git clone chromium

Tags: git, google-chrome, github, chromium

I want to download chromium source code, it is here :

- https://github.com/chromium/chromium
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/

I want to understand why they say :

**"don't use git clone! Instead, follow the instructions on how to get the code."**

What is the problem with using git clone ?

I tried their instructions :

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

And always at some point I get errors (I retried 5 times) :

```
1>error: 49528 bytes of body are still expected10.69 GiB | 824.00 KiB/s
1>fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
1>fatal: early EOF
1>fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Can I use git clone ? please explain to me why they say don't use it.

Comment: Because the repository is really huge. `git clone` is more likely to fail than the instructions. The instructions probably wrap some git commands to do a much smaller clone. You could try `fetch chromium --no-history`.

Comment: I tried it : `fetch --no-history chromium` it worked, the size is small, only 1.15gb, the normal fetch is more than 20gb and I always get an error, this one works, thank you so much.

Comment: update : the final size on disk is 20.4Gb, `fetch --no-history chromium` worked in one go without any errors, but the normal `fetch chromium` gave errors in all of the 5 attempts at different times, this is a bit weird but I am glad that something worked and now I have the source code locally.